# C - What option do I use to produce a listing file?

Tags: c, gcc

I am new to the C programming language and gcc.

I am trying to decipher a rather complex C program.  I would like to read a helpful listing file instead of the source file.

I am looking for a listing file created by the gcc compiler that contains:

1. the source code for all the includes
2. xref = cross reference listing
3. reference to where the variable is declared.  For example, if the line contains `i++;`, then      a note saying were `i` is declared.

I did a search for this, but gcc has so many options, I got lost.

If there is a better place to ask my question, please let me know.

Comment: Listings are so 1960-s! Get an integrated development environment instead :)  (take with a grain of salt)

Comment: Even Cobol had a cross reference as an option.  How do I go about understanding a C program with two comments besides the GNU license?

Comment: Cross-referencing is the easiest thing in modern IDEs. You right-click a variable or a function, and select "go to definition" or "find all usages", and the IDE finds it for you. No paper copies, no printers, it's almost as easy as navigating hyperlinks.

Comment: Are you sure you want to see "the source code for all the includes"?  Even stdlib.h and stdio.h?  Unless you're hacking glibc, the info files might be more helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I AM old-school, and what the OP needs is pre-processor output, and yes it can be more edifying than an IDE.  The preprocessor handles all of the # statements, like #include and #ifdef.  So it shows you what eventually becomes the input to the compiler.
The g++ man page explains the 4 steps:
        preprocessing, compilation, assembly and linking

and it goes on to explain that the sequence can be stopped at any point.  Then under "Preprocessor Options", the way to control this is explained.  As another post stated, -E will do the trick, but that is only part of the answer.  For finer control use the -f family of options, such as -fdirectives-only.  So probably what the OP wants is:

```
    gcc  -E  -fdirectives-only  -o MySrc.lst  MySrc.cpp
```

For those using C++, I recommend using g++ directly:

```
    g++  -E  -fdirectives-only  -o MySrc.lst  MySrc.cpp
```

The desired listing is then in MySrc.lst

Answer (score 2):

I understand your dilemma.  Years ago, I tried to do exactly what you are doing, but eventually I gave up.  Although one literally *could* do it, the result would drown the relevant code in so much code irrelevant to the problem at hand as to be useless.

I am afraid that you are going to have to learn how to read C code in the C way.  If the code is complex, and you're a beginner, then -- for the moment -- you're probably in over your head.

If you want to try it anyway, then look at the names of the source's several *.h "header" files.  Pick out three or four header files that seem to you likely to address the central part of the problem.  Read these files first.  Broaden your reading from there.  This isn't easy, until you get the swing of it.

Good luck.

Comment: Here is how I invoked cxref:

cxref -html -index-all  -xref-all  BitHoist.c

I do not see a list of my variables. I do not see source code.  I do not see the code for all my includes.

Robert

Answer (score 2):

A different approach. If you use i.e. Vim then run cscope on the code.

For example I have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> as a cscope trigger. If I am in a function:

```
01 #define SOME_BLAH 33
02 
03 void foo() {
04     printf("%d\n", SOME_BLAH); /* <- cursor on SOME_BLAH; 
05                                   trigger + G jumps to line 1 */
06 }
07 
08 void bar() {
09     foo(); /* <- Cursor on foo I hit trigger, G and I jump to line 3 */
10 }
```

Equally you can jump like this across files, into includes, list functions calling a specific function, list functions a function is calling, list files including a file, jump to where variables are defined etc. All within a couple of key strokes.

Every jump is added to a LIFO stack and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> brings one back to where I entered the last jump-to command.

---

Additionally add i.e. `Taglist` and you get a list on the side of the window with all defines, variables, functions etc. sorted in a list.

---

Another option is to compile the code with i.e. `-ggdb` and run it in an IDE like Code::Blocks, use DDD or the like – and step trough the code as it run as process. Can be quite educational.

---

Comment: I'll have to consider using an IDE.  That means trying to learn Xcode on the Mac.

Answer (score 1):

You don't.  You use a program that does the listing separately.  It's silly for compilers to have to know about printing too.

I recommend [a2ps](http://www.gnu.org/software/a2ps/).  For a cross-reference, look for [cxref](http://www.gedanken.org.uk/software/cxref/).

Comment: Thanks.  I'm looking into cxref.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question #1 it is possible to see the source code for all the includes by looking at the preprocessor output using `gcc -E`.  However, that code will probably be more difficult to understand so it's probably not really what you are looking for, although I have found it useful in some instance for things that I have needed to do.

Comment: Part of the problem is that the compiler doesn't see the code as you do.