# How to generate a source code listing with gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Other Fortran compilers have an option to generate a source code listing (typically with a `.lst` file extension) that shows source code, symbol cross reference, common blocks, etc. I cannot find any documentation on how to do this with gfortran. For example, on Linux:

```
Intel: ifort -list ...
IBM: xlf -qsource ...
PGI: pgf90 -Mlist ...
SUN: f95 -Xlist ...
```

Comment: @Usman thanksfor adding the right tag to bring this post to our attention. However, please do not use syntax highlighting for every word that happens to be a tag. `It` can `make` harder `to` read `the` post.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343950/c-what-option-do-i-use-to-produce-a-listing-file